# Atom not included in TypeScript compilation context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, atom-editor

i already read tons os posts and none of them actualy helped me.
I'm using Atom to develop a react/typescript application.
Atom keeps printing me an error:

> "The file "C:/****/src/components/teste.tsx" is not included in the TypeScript compilation context.  If this is not intended, please check the "files" or "filesGlob" section of your tsconfig.json file.at line 1 col 1

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "system",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"isolatedModules": false,
"jsx": "react",
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"declaration": false,
"noImplicitAny": false,
"removeComments": true,
"noLib": false,
"preserveConstEnums": true,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
},
"filesGlob": [
"**/*.ts",
"**/*.tsx"
]
}
```

And this is my teste.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class Teste extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      Hello, asdas
      <Testando />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Teste;
```

When i run the project in browser-sync all works fine, but those errors in Atom are anoying, someone has a clue how to solve this?

(Sorry for my english)
Cheers

Comment: Did you try to add in your *tsconfig.json* these following attributes : `"atom": {"rewriteTsconfig": true }` and `"files": []` ?

Comment: @JeanMel Did it now added `"files": ["components/teste.tsx", "dependencies.tsx", "main.tsx"]` the editor brings all application files to the array, but the error persists even restarting the editor, the main.tsx and dependencies.tsx dont bring this error ONLY the components/teste.tsx

Answer (score 0):

> someone has a clue how to solve this

- The tsconfig.json must be *above* in the directory where the file exists
- Restart atom.